# Using OR in if condition with String value in C#.Net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How can I put the below statement in C#.Net.

If(strValue =="ABC" || strValue =="EFG" || strValue =="IJK")
Some code implementation.

It gives me error (Operand || cannot be applied to type bool or string) , when I use the above statement.

Comment: The if clause you posted doesn't look wrong. Could you please add more code? Actually, if you use Visual Studio, the invalid line should be underlined in red.

Comment: your code is pretty straight forward and right ,provide more code snippet for better answers

Answer (score 1):

Please try :

```
        if(strValue.Equals("ABC") || strValue.Equals("EFG") || strValue.Equals("IJK"))
        {

        }
```

You may not write "if" with a capital i and the function "Equals" work better on string comparison